# How can I make the "Preview Post" button save and preview in the same window?

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, previous-post-link, previews

When you choose "Preview", which is actually a link,

```
<a class="preview button" href="?p=52&amp;preview=true"
id="post-preview" tabindex="4">Preview</a>
```

the post is saved and the preview opens in a new window.

I'm sure there is a javascript event attached to this button, I'd like to override it so that it saves and then preview link opens in the same tab / window.

[image: Picture.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without modifying the core:

```
add_action('admin_footer','preview_same_window');

function preview_same_window(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

     jQuery('.preview.button').unbind().removeAttr('target');

            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery('.preview.button').unbind().removeAttr('target');
            },250);

    });

    </script>
    <?php
}
```